# How can I create the SQL Server database scheme for a Docker image based on an existing DbContext with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework, yaml

Started working with Docker images recently, and my main problem is that while my `docker-compose` can spin up the api, and the database I need, what it lacks is the actual scheme of the database that the entities within my API project look for when getting data.

So I have a `DbContext` already, all the entities, and I namely cant figure out for the life of me how to build the database in the SQL Server image based on the context that is already in my API project.

`docker-compose` file for reference:

```yaml
networks:
  event_localhost:
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: spc-eventapi
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - event_localhost
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__EventDb: 'Server=db,1433;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word;'
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    networks:
      - event_localhost
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: 'Pass@word'
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
version: '3.9'
```

Context and entities: https://github.com/SantaPoneCentralDev/santaponecentral/tree/Docker/SPC-2021/api/event/event/Event.Data/Entities

Comment: A SQL Server database is an MDF file.  In Net library the mdf file can either be mounted on a sql server or not mounted on a server.  Local Host usually means not mounted.  You can build a database mounted on a server using SQL Sever Management Studio and create the database/tables/properties using the SSMS explorer; or do similar with the Database menu in VS.

Comment: Are you using [Code First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) or [Database First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) in EF? If it's Code First you should be able to point it to an empty database and it will run the migrations to create the table schema and seed to populate it with initial data for you. The DB container only needs to create an empty database for EF to use.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I scaffolded the entities code first. If I can run the migrations to the spun up DB, that'd be awesome, but Im actually not entirely sure how to even begin doing something like that, actually

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked was using the functions that entity framework allows, being .EnsureCreated()

Adding the following lines of code to the Configure method in Startup creates the schema and DB in the container if it doesn't already exist

```cs
            // Ensures DB is created against container
            IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            using IServiceScope serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            SantaPoneCentralDatabaseContext dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SantaPoneCentralDatabaseContext>();
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```